# CTRL-] keys not working with very specific tags

Tags: tags, help-system

So, I'm trying to use vim's help tags in my notes files, so that i can easily reach them (without using ex command or making a new keymapping).

For that, i used:

```
set tags=$VIMRUNTIME/doc/tags
```

to set the tags file to the one for the help/doc.

Now it *does* work for most tags, but i noticed that some tags just won't work when used with `CTRL-]`. Example:

```
*E426* "works
*:ta*  "E426: tag not found: ta
*:tag* "doesn't work, goes to *tag* instead of *:tag*
*tag*  "works
```

As seen in the example above, some just doesn't work. Though, they do work fine when used with the `:h` or `:help` command.

And yes, i did check in the `tags` file previously mentioned (which can be found at `$VIMRUNTIME/doc/tags`) if the non-working tags were present, and *they were* (not surprising since they do work with the ex command `:help` and it's variation, but not on this specific case).

I did `:helptags $VIMRUNTIME/doc` just to make sure and compared the hash of the new and old one, though they were the same, so problem likely isn't coming from that.

I'm also aware of existing solution like [VimNotes](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=828) or [helplink.vim](https://github.com/arp242/helplink.vim) but:

- The former would require me to use help file structure, which i prefer not to (compared to the workflow previously described that wouldn't require me to use any special/specific filetype or template).
- The latter would only link to generated urls of the docs in different templates.

Using Vim 8.2, compiled Oct 26 2020, Including all features.

Anyway, I'm a bit lost as to why it doesn't work for the specified tags in my previous example. Any input appreciated.

Comment: <c-]> is not quite the same as `:help`, which usually accepts abbreviations. It’s more the equivalent of `:tag` which, afaik, needs the whole match. (Try `:tag :ta`, see if that’s different from `:help :ta`.) Note that you can set `keywordprg` to `:help` so that K works almost like you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! `:tag :ta` as a ex command works just about the same as `:help :ta` when used inside/with the previously mentioned examples. As for using `keywordprg`, I tried doing `setl keywordprg=:help` and, noticed that using `K` now *only* work on `*:ta*` but not on `*:tag*` (still put cursor on `*tag*` instead) :/ @D.BenKnoble