# <CWORD> not always working with symbols

Tags: cword

As question imply, I'm trying to make a command based on the word under cursor, but that is between two character, in this example, asterisk.

Inspired from [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Word_under_cursor_for_command), I made:

```
map <F3> "zyiw:exe "h "expand("<cword>")""<CR>
```

Where i use it on `h` for testing.

```
*E426* "works
*:ta*  "works
*:tag* "only match *tag* instead of *:tag*
*tag*  "works
```

But even though it seems to work fine for `*:ta*`, it doesn't seem to work right for `*:tag*`.

I'm aware one need to add characters/symbol to `iskeyword` so that it is correctly matched as a `word`, but in this instance, i didn't need to do so (though that only worked for `*:ta*` and not `*:tag*` as previously mentioned).

Slightly related to [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27840/ctrl-keys-not-working-with-very-specific-tags) post.

Comment: I would have written your mapping as `nnoremap <F3> :execute 'help' expand('<cword>')<cr>` but I’m not sure it makes a difference

Comment: yeah...any idea to make this work? I tried what was showed in the wikia linked in my post, but that didn't quite worked (which is why i ended up using `cword` in the first place) @D.BenKnoble

Comment: Try using `<cWORD>` instead. That seemed to work for me.

Comment: this...actually work!!! I do not know what is the difference (looked into help but didn't see any difference beside that one is uppercase and the other isn't) but it did took me a longer time than i thought to know this...so thank you (and feel free to post this as answer if you want). @Tumbler41

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [`<cword>`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Ccword%3E), which essentially uses the characters in [`'iskeyword'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27) to determine what a "word" means, and also [`<cWORD>`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3CcWORD%3E) which matches a sequence of non-whitespace characters.

For the former, `<cword>`, by default it will not include symbols such as `:` and `*`, so in your specific case, when your cursor is on `*:tag*` it will only get `tag`, and when your cursor is on `*:ta*` it will only get `ta`.

You seem to be under the impression that it's behaving differently because of how the `:help` command works when it doesn't match a help topic exactly.

The help system has tags for both the command `:tag` and an explanation on what a `tag` is. So [`:help :tag`](https://vimhelp.org/tagsrch.txt.html#%3Atag) will take you to the former, while [`:help tag`](https://vimhelp.org/tagsrch.txt.html#tag) will take you to the latter.

On the other hand, there's no exact match for `ta` by itself. So when you look for `:help ta`, Vim will try to "guess" what you meant by that. In particular, it will try to see if it's a valid Ex command (by prepending a `:`) and, since there is such a help topic, it will take you to the help on [`:ta`](https://vimhelp.org/tagsrch.txt.html#%3Ata).

If you want to find the exact expression inside the `*`s, you can either use `<cWORD>` and then use Vimscript functions to filter out the `*`s from the resulting expression, or you can use a yank to capture it. For example:

```
nnoremap <F3> :exe 'help '.substitute(expand('<cWORD>'), '^\*\\|\*$', '', 'g')<CR>
```

Comment: perfect. Also illustrated the misunderstanding i had previously :)