# Conversion of Ex command to mapping not always working

Tags: key-bindings, ex-mode

Here, I'm using a mapping from [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27855/cword-not-always-working-with-symbols) post. Edited it to my liking like so:

```
nnoremap <F3> :execute 'help' expand('<cWORD>')<CR>
```

that works. Problem is, i wanted to add `| only` so that the help window become the only visible opened window.
I tried this in Ex mode:

```
:execute "h "expand("<cWORD>")"| only"
```

This works as intended.

Now when i try to do it in a mapping:

```
nnoremap <F3> :execute "h "expand("<cWORD>")"| only"<CR>
```

Doesn't seem to work.

I think it might be due to the position of the quotes, but after some experiments, i couldn't fix it myself.

How come the mapping doesn't work, when the Ex command does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help` sees `|` as its argument, so I suggest to write a simple function.

```
function! s:search_help(str)
  exec 'help '.a:str
  only
endfunction
nnoremap <F3> :call <SID>search_help(expand('<cword>'))<CR>
```

As pointed in comment, when using `:map` command `|` should be `<bar>` (`:h key-notation`), so there is an one-line solution:

```
nnoremap <F3> :exec 'h '.expand('<cword>').' <bar> only'<CR>
```

Comment: didn't know :O. Thanks!

Comment: You can write `only` instead of `execute 'only'`; this is true for all ex-commands (you only need execute when doing string interpolation into the command, and to protect certain things like `|` from being arguments to commands)

Comment: Note also that `|` in mappings should be `<bar>`, a common point of confusion